# org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException when running through master runner(cucumber report generation) running fine individually through karate

Tags: cucumber, karate, junit5, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.AssertionError
com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList$Cache.lookup(PolyglotList.java:180)
com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList.<init>(PolyglotList.java:73)
com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotList.create(PolyglotList.java:96)
com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotHostAccess.toList(PolyglotHostAccess.java:107)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.asJavaObject(HostToTypeNode.java:384)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.convertImpl(HostToTypeNode.java:194)
com.oracle.truffle.host.HostToTypeNode.doCached(HostToTypeNode.java:118)
```

It throws the above error when it is run using below master runner and fails to run the java method.

```
package tests;

import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.Configuration;
import net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reporting.ExtentReport;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class MasterTestRunner {

    // this will run all *.feature files  
    /*@Karate.Test
    Karate testAll() {
        return Karate.run().relativeTo(getClass());
    }*/

    //Karate Parallel Runner
    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        final Results results = Runner.path("classpath:tests/features").hook(new ExtentReport()).tags("@test")
                .outputCucumberJson(true).outputJunitXml(true).parallel(1);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }

    //Boiler Plate for Cucumber report generation
    public static void generateReport(final String karateOutputPath) {
        final Collection<File> jsonFiles = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(karateOutputPath), new String[]{"json"}, true);
        final ArrayList<String> jsonPaths = new ArrayList<>(jsonFiles.size());
        jsonFiles.forEach(file -> jsonPaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        final Configuration config = new Configuration(new File("target"), "Karate test");
        System.out.println("config report " + config.getBuildNumber());
        final ReportBuilder reportBuilder = new ReportBuilder(jsonPaths, config);
        reportBuilder.generateReports();
    }
}
```

when it is run individually in feature file it is successful.
The carate test is like below.

```
Feature: karate testing

  @test
  Scenario: Karate test case
    * def acts = [  {  "label": "BUSINESS","name": "David","id": "u374892","type": "DIVISION"},{"label": "Division","name":"MILLER","id": "u236478","type": "BUSINESS"}]
    * def data1 = [{"UserName": "ABENANTE","UserID": "u109238","Role": "BUSINESS"},{"UserName": "Louis","UserID": "u784784","Role": "DIVISION"}]
    * def desk = utils.returnIds(data1, 2, acts, "DESK")
    * print desk
```

The java method from utils starts like

```
public static List<Map<String, Object>> returnIds(List<Map<String, Object>> listOfAllIds, int numberOfIds, List<Map<String, Object>> listOfIds, String role)
```

For Karate the dependencies are

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <karate.version>1.1.0</karate.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- For Karate Begin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am not sure what might cause this issue.

Comment: in such cases I can't help unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I will do.